# How to create a sphere with strings that rotates toward the mouse pointer in css and js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

The output I want;

[image]

> *I want to make a sphere with names, but without curving/bending the names. I also want to make it spin in the direction of the mouse pointer.*
>
> If i use this rotate property, my words got curved.

```css
@keyframes rotate {
 0% {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
 }
}
.circ{
  border: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#sphere{
 animation: rotate 6s linear infinite;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
}
.circ:nth-child(1) {
 transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(2) {
 transform: rotateX(30deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(3) {
 transform: rotateX(60deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(4) {
 transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(5) {
 transform: rotateX(120deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(6) {
 transform: rotateX(150deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(7) {
 transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(8) {
 transform: rotateX(210deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="sphere">
  <div class="circ">aaaaa</div>
  <div class="circ">bbbbb</div>
  <div class="circ">ccccc</div>
  <div class="circ">ddddd</div>
  <div class="circ">eeeee</div>
  <div class="circ">ffffffff</div>
</div>
```

and so on..

Comment: if i use this rotate property, my words got curved.
<div id="sphere">
  <div class="circ">aaaaa</div>
  <div class="circ">bbbbb</div>
  <div class="circ">ccccc</div>
  <div class="circ">ddddd</div>
  <div class="circ">eeeee</div>
  <div class="circ">ffffffff</div>
 </div>
.circ:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateX(30deg);
}
and so on..

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/920nzveu/

Comment: hey, check the image I just uploaded, I wanted like that. I have just uploaded a small part of my code cause I didn't understand the proper way to upload.

Comment: I see, for that you don't rotate but move the words in 3D space. A bit more complicated, and not really explained in the space of a comment. (and too broad as regular question for stack overflow, you need to do more research first)

Comment: I'm not picturing entirely what you're after visually based on the image and description. It sounds like you want words attached to a transparent sphere at different levels of the Z plane and as the mouse moves around the sphere the 3d sphere will spin the opposite direction with words coming closer on the Z plane as they come near the mouse [like this](http://nkunited.de/jquery/plugins/svg3dtagcloudV2/example1.html)? Either way this is a pretty broad one.

Comment: Yes like this and I would love to do some research. But before that can you tell me how can I add another feather like when I zoom/scroll the mouse the sphere gets bigger but not the words.

Comment: You're looking for [TagCanvas](https://github.com/goat1000/TagCanvas).

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: It's complicated.**

Basically you want a game engine loop and some advanced visualization library like D3 or Pixi.js. You might could get away with straight css/html if you only have a few words, but it might be laggy Here's the approach I would take:

1. Give each word a coordinate in relation to the center of a 3d sphere.
2. Do some math and rotate your sphere towards the mouse. (You probably want to use a vector library like gl-matrix.)
3. Update each word's position by applying the sphere's rotation to it.
4. Apply camera lens transform to each word's location, or just scale them by z-distance to get a perspective effect.
5. Render words using whatever tech your library uses, like sprites or vectors.